# Coq fixpoint defintion numerated by natural numbers.(type of (n+1)'s type depends on (n)'s type)

Tags: coq

I want to inductivly define type urt.
I want to know something about (urt n) while I define (urt n.+1).
(I will use the projection on the second element pr1 inside the definition of urt.)
Idenitifier sigT creates type of dependent pairs; pr1, pr2 are projections from such pair.

```
 Context (qsigT: forall (A : Type) (P : forall a : A, Type), Type).
 Context (qpr1: forall (A : Type) (P : forall a : A, Type), (@qsigT A P) -> A ).
 Inductive Unit : Type :=
  | tt : Unit.
 Inductive Bool : Type :=
  | true : Bool
  | false : Bool.
 Fixpoint urt (n:nat): Type.

 Proof.
  refine (@qsigT Bool _).

  destruct n.

  exact (fun _ => Unit).
  exact (fun q =>
          (@qsigT (urt n) (fun q => (*error below occurs because of using (urt n)*)
            Unit+Unit+Unit (*I also cannot use here something like (qpr1 q), because of the same reasons*)
          ))
  ).
  Show Proof.

 Defined.
 Check fun (q : urt 4) => qpr1 q. (*Error!*)

 Context (y:nat).
 Check fun (q : urt y) => qpr1 q. (*Error here, need to be solved*)
```

The error is 
`The term "q" has type "urt (S (S (S (S O))))" while it is expected to have type "Type".`
How should I change the definition?

Comment: Please post a self-contained example, in particular, we'd need to see what `pr2` is.

Comment: @ejgallego , I changed code a lot, now it is pr1, but question is the same.

Comment: The first example should be `qpr1 _ _ q` in order for your example to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `urt` definition has a top level fixpoint thus you need to destruct `y` for the fixpoint to reduce to a `sigT _ _` form. (Hint: try to use `(S y)` in your `Check` statement).

It is hard to guess what you'd like to do, but a possible solution would be to delay the fixpoint after the `sigT` constructor.

```
 Definition urt (n : nat) : Type.
 Proof.
  refine (@qsigT Bool _).
  revert n.
  fix urt 1.
  intros [|n].
  exact (fun _ => Unit).
  exact (fun q =>
          (@qsigT (urt n q) (fun q => (*error below occurs because of using (urt n)*)
            (Unit+Unit+Unit)%type (*I also cannot use here something like (qpr1 q), because of the same reasons*)
          ))
  ).
  Show Proof.

 Defined.
 Check fun (q : urt 4) => qpr1 _ _ q.
 Context (y:nat).
 Check fun (q : urt y) => qpr1 _ _ q.
```